# For generator $g$ of multiplicative group: if $\log_g (f^3) = 3x$, then $\log_g (f) = x$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, discrete-logarithms

$F_q$ is finite field, $g$ - generating element of multiplicative group. Assume that for some element $f$  from multiplicative group we have $\log_g (f^3) = 3x$.
Is it true, that $\log_g (f) = x$?

Comment: Have you looked at $\mathbb{F}_4$? All non-zero elements cube to $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician no, I haven't. But 2 cube is 8, which is 0 $mod 4$. So, not all of them.

Comment: You do not understand what $\mathbb{F}_4$ is. It is not $\mathbb{Z}_4=\{0,1,2,3\}$. A finite field has a multiplicative group which is cyclic of order $q-1$.

Comment: Or look at $\mathbb{F}_7$, which may be easier to grasp.  This is of course not $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but since $7$ is prime $\mathbb{F}_7$ is isomorphic with the nonzero elements $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.  Then $3^3\equiv 5^3 (\equiv 6)$ does not imply $3\equiv 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question may be rephrased as follows:

> Does $g^{3x}=f^3$ imply $g^x = f$ ?

Let $\log_g (f) = y$. Then $g^{3x}=f^3=g^{3y}$ iff $3x \equiv 3y \bmod q-1$, because $g$ has order $q-1$.

Therefore, it is true that $x=y$ if $\gcd(3,q-1)=1$.

It may be false otherwise. For instance, take $q=16$.

Comment: Could you please add more details about this $gcd(3, q-1) = 1$? I'didn't really get that. Why is it so important?

Comment: @Ihf thank you! I've finally understood everything, except one thing. Why are we consider $3x \equiv 3y mod (q-1)$ and not $mod(q)$?

Comment: @Ihf, gee, thanks again! I would definetely kiss you, if I could.